# Fop table not displayed correctly in rtl mode

Tags: xml, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have the following fop code generated for displaying a table with 2 column and 2 row with some data.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:simple-page-master writing-mode="rl-tb" master-name="pagesize" page-height="238.5pt" page-width="1020.78pt" margin-left="0pt" margin-right="0pt" margin-top="0pt" margin-bottom="0pt">
        <fo:region-body margin-top="0pt" margin-bottom="0pt"/>
        <fo:region-before extent="0pt"/>
        <fo:region-after extent="0pt"/>
    </fo:simple-page-master>
</fo:layout-master-set>

<fo:page-sequence master-reference="pagesize">
    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
        <fo:block-container absolute-position="absolute" writing-mode="rl-tb" font-family="Liberation Sans" font-size="13.25pt" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" top="20pt" right="20pt" width="1020.78pt" height="238.5pt" background-color="brown">
            <fo:table wrap-option="no-wrap" overflow="hidden" border-collapse="separate" background-color="green">
                <fo:table-column column-width="69.5625pt"/>
                <fo:table-column column-width="69.5625pt"/>
                <fo:table-body>
                    <fo:table-row background-color="#FFFFFF">
                        <fo:table-cell padding-right="2.48438pt" padding-left="2.48438pt" padding-top="0.49687pt" padding-bottom="0.49687pt" height="24.84375pt" relative-align="baseline" display-align="center" overflow="hidden">
                            <fo:block-container text-align="right" display-align="center" white-space-treatment="preserve" white-space-collapse="false" linefeed-treatment="preserve" overflow="hidden">
                                <fo:block/>
                            </fo:block-container>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell padding-right="2.48438pt" padding-left="2.48438pt" padding-top="0.49687pt" padding-bottom="0.49687pt" height="24.84375pt" relative-align="baseline" display-align="center" overflow="hidden">
                            <fo:block-container text-align="center" display-align="center" white-space-treatment="preserve" white-space-collapse="false" linefeed-treatment="preserve" overflow="hidden">
                                <fo:block>Fiscal Calendar</fo:block>
                            </fo:block-container>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-row background-color="#FFFFFF">
                        <fo:table-cell padding-right="2.48438pt" padding-left="2.48438pt" padding-top="0.49687pt" padding-bottom="0.49687pt" height="24.84375pt" relative-align="baseline" display-align="center" overflow="hidden">
                            <fo:block-container text-align="right" display-align="center" white-space-treatment="preserve" white-space-collapse="false" linefeed-treatment="preserve" overflow="hidden">
                                <fo:block>Accounts</fo:block>
                            </fo:block-container>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell padding-right="2.48438pt" padding-left="2.48438pt" padding-top="0.49687pt" padding-bottom="0.49687pt" height="24.84375pt" relative-align="baseline" display-align="center" overflow="hidden">
                            <fo:block-container text-align="right" display-align="center" white-space-treatment="preserve" white-space-collapse="false" linefeed-treatment="preserve" overflow="hidden">
                                <fo:block>#</fo:block>
                            </fo:block-container>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>
        </fo:block-container>
    </fo:flow>
</fo:page-sequence>

</fo:root>
```

Problem: Table not right aligned in rtl mode but the contents within the cells are right aligned which is correct by the way. I checked the output, and see that writting-mode is applied to the table cells correctly displaying text right to left but the table as such is not right aligned despite giving right and absolute-position attribute to the block-container. I tried giving the same attributes to fo:table still it did not work.

I check the apache fop docs and I have used the attributes correctly. Let me know if I am missing something.

please check below Image for output generated by the above code.
[image: RTL Image]

Comment: Please post the full XSL FO, certainly your XSL FO does not start with layout-master-set and end with root. You are missing the whole top part for us to diagnose.

Comment: @KevinBrown OP accidentally removed the `fo:root` element in a [previous revision](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42560731/revisions#rev2717fb4d-c1ce-425d-8a49-e0de073466c7), I edited it back (not that there is anything significant there)

Comment: @KevinBrown.. When your diagnosing please check for the table element to be right aligned not the block container. If, I set the block-container width to be equal to table element width then you can notice the table being aligned right. I want to know why right and position attribute for table element is not making it right aligned.

Answer (score 1):

While this is not an answer, it could be. Tested with RenderX, output is this:

[image]

Which if this is what you expect, you should file a bug report with FOP. The table should be built right to left.

Comment: did you consider my FOP code for the generation or was it your custom FOP code?

Comment: I am actually converting the fop code into bytes and then generating png image and pdf out of it using java. Do you have any idea if this kind of conversion can be a drawback for FOP table not being aligned on right side?

Comment: IMHO, no. It's XSL FO. It doesn't work in FOP, report a bug.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Will report it.